# Cannot simulate video traffic between two hosts in Mininet

Tags: video, traffic, packets, mininet, network-traffic

I am trying to simulate video traffic in Mininet, so that one host sends it to another. I did what the answer in [this question](https://ask.opendaylight.org/question/1880/simulating-video-traffic-for-odl-app/) suggests, which means :

- I downloaded an mp4 video and transferred it to my Mininet VM.
- I installed VLC player on my Mininet VM.
- I used the command :

  ```
  sudo mn --topo single, 2
  ```
- Then I ran the command :

  ```
  mininet> h1 vlc-wrapper $VideoFile --sout '#rtp{dst=10.0.0.2,port=1234}'
  ```

  where for $VideoFile I placed both `$MY_FILE_PATH` and `MY_FILE_PATH`, but my console shows nothing... It shows only :

  ```
  mininet>
  ```

  and it is as if something is running, and it stops with Ctrl+C. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to prepare `h2` to receive it. Go to `h2`, open `network stream`.

Comment: @ShinQian thanks for your answer but I did not understand... Could you tell me when exactly I should do that?

Comment: before starting on `h1`

Comment: @ShinQian ok.. so in `h2` I just type `network stream`?